# SquareSpace using other domain / keeping present

Tags: squarespace

I am seeking to use a domain already purchased elsewhere within a square space website.

Currently I have the domain mapped; for instance you type in the actual .com / www.coolguy.com

You are then redirected to coolguy.squarespace.com

That's fine, but then the squarespace is still present in the URL while the user is browsing. My question is; **is there a way to completely use my .com domain that was purchased elsewhere with a 'paid' squarespace website?**

I understand you can 'buy' a .com with them and that will work of course; but what about if it's purchased elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to map your existing `.com` domain to your `.squarespace.com` site using [the instruction provided here](http://help.squarespace.com/customer/portal/articles/413088-mapping-a-domain-general-instructions-).

The instructions also have domain registrar specific instructions [at the end](http://help.squarespace.com/customer/portal/articles/413088-mapping-a-domain-general-instructions-#provider-specific-guides) for the following registrars.

You can click to view our guides for mapping your domain if it is hosted with a specific domain provider below.

```
Dotster
Dreamhost
easyDNS
Enom
GoDaddy
Hover.com
IWantMyName.com
Namecheap
Nettica
Network Solutions
1&1
```

Comment: Will this completely transfer, or is this just for a redirect; similar to what I described is currently in place? Meaning while on the website and browsing you will continue to see the actual .com domain?

Comment: What this will do is, if a visitor accesses coolguy.com it will serve up the site from coolguy.squarespace.com. Is that what you want? I visited coolguy.squarespace.com (assuming that was the real site in question) as well as coolguy.com and they are not redirecting as you've stated above. So is coolguy.com the actual site or did you just post it as an example?

Comment: That was just an example. I don't want a redirect; a complete domain transfer as if the site was not developed with square space.

Comment: Ok. That's what the domain mapping I suggested above will do. So once you do it, and wait for it to propagate, all your pages from `yoursite.squarespace.com` will be served up via `yoursite.com`. So to anyone visiting the `yoursite.com`, it won't be obvious that the content is coming from `yoursite.squarespace.com`. Here's an example. This site is build with squarespace -- http://darrenbooth.com/